# How do I creat CSV file with webscraped content from several URLs?

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to create a CSV file from webscraped content. The content is from [FinViz.com](https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=ftft)
 I want to scrape the table from this website 20 times for 20 different stocks and input all the content into a CSV file. Within my code, I generate a list of stocks from a scrape of twitter content. The list of stocks that is generated is the same list that I want to get information on from the FinViz.com tables.

Here is my code:

```
import csv
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

twiturl = "https://twitter.com/ACInvestorBlog"
twitpage = urllib.request.urlopen(twiturl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(twitpage,"html.parser")

print(soup.title.text)

tweets = [i.text for i in soup.select('a.twitter-cashtag.pretty-link.js-nav b')]
print(tweets)

url_base = "https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="
url_list = [url_base + tckr for tckr in tweets]

for url in url_list:

    fpage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    fsoup = BeautifulSoup(fpage, 'html.parser')

    # scrape single page and add data to list
    # write datalist
with open('today.csv', 'a') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
# write header row
writer.writerow(map(lambda e : e.text, fsoup.find_all('td', {'class':'snapshot-td2-cp'})))

# write body row
writer.writerow(map(lambda e : e.text, fsoup.find_all('td', {'class':'snapshot-td2'})))
```

**The trouble that I am running into is that my CSV file only has the webscraped data from the last item in the list. Instead I want the entire list in a sequence of rows.**

Here is what my CSV file looks like:

```
Index,P/E,EPS (ttm),Insider Own,Shs Outstand,Perf Week,Market Cap,Forward P/E,EPS next Y,Insider Trans,Shs Float,Perf Month,Income,PEG,EPS next Q,Inst Own,Short Float,Perf Quarter,Sales,P/S,EPS this Y,Inst Trans,Short Ratio,Perf Half Y,Book/sh,P/B,EPS next Y,ROA,Target Price,Perf Year,Cash/sh,P/C,EPS next 5Y,ROE,52W Range,Perf YTD,Dividend,P/FCF,EPS past 5Y,ROI,52W High,Beta,Dividend %,Quick Ratio,Sales past 5Y,Gross Margin,52W Low,ATR,Employees,Current Ratio,Sales Q/Q,Oper. Margin,RSI (14),Volatility,Optionable,Debt/Eq,EPS Q/Q,Profit Margin,Rel Volume,Prev Close,Shortable,LT Debt/Eq,Earnings,Payout,Avg Volume,Price,Recom,SMA20,SMA50,SMA200,Volume,Change

-,-,-1.75,7.94%,79.06M,-22.52%,296.48M,-,-1.74,-4.61%,72.41M,-23.16%,-85.70M,-,-0.36,62.00%,3.21%,1.63%,15.10M,19.63,-197.00%,18.05%,2.57,66.67%,-0.65,-,-8.10%,-127.70%,12.17,-6.25%,0.93,4.03,-,146.70%,2.05 - 5.86,3.59%,-,-,-,385.80%,-36.01%,-,-,1.30,-,76.50%,82.93%,0.41,100,1.30,-59.60%,-,36.98,16.13% 9.32%,Yes,-,90.00%,-,0.82,3.63,Yes,-,Nov 08,-,902.43K,3.75,2.30,-22.08%,-10.43%,11.96%,"742,414",3.31%
```

Comment: indent writer ...

Comment: You close the `today.csv` file at the end, after `writer = csv.writer(file)`. Be sure to indent those next two lines (`writer.writerow()`).  Otherwise, you're just opening the CSV, creating a writer, then closing it. *Then* do you try to access the, now closed, csv file.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to open your output file first, rather than keep on opening/closing it for each URL that you fetch. Exception handling is needed to catch cases where the URL does not exist.

Also on your output, you should open the file with `newline=''` to avoid extra empty lines being written to the file:

```
import csv
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

write_header = True

twiturl = "https://twitter.com/ACInvestorBlog"
twitpage = urllib.request.urlopen(twiturl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(twitpage,"html.parser")

print(soup.title.text)

tweets = [i.text for i in soup.select('a.twitter-cashtag.pretty-link.js-nav b')]
print(tweets)

url_base = "https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="
url_list = [url_base + tckr for tckr in tweets]

with open('today.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)

    for url in url_list:
        try:
            fpage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
            fsoup = BeautifulSoup(fpage, 'html.parser')

            # write header row (once)
            if write_header:
                writer.writerow(map(lambda e : e.text, fsoup.find_all('td', {'class':'snapshot-td2-cp'})))
                write_header = False

            # write body row
            writer.writerow(map(lambda e : e.text, fsoup.find_all('td', {'class':'snapshot-td2'})))            
        except urllib.error.HTTPError:
            print("{} - not found".format(url))
```

So `today.csv` would start like:

```
Index,P/E,EPS (ttm),Insider Own,Shs Outstand,Perf Week,Market Cap,Forward P/E,EPS next Y,Insider Trans,Shs Float,Perf Month,Income,PEG,EPS next Q,Inst Own,Short Float,Perf Quarter,Sales,P/S,EPS this Y,Inst Trans,Short Ratio,Perf Half Y,Book/sh,P/B,EPS next Y,ROA,Target Price,Perf Year,Cash/sh,P/C,EPS next 5Y,ROE,52W Range,Perf YTD,Dividend,P/FCF,EPS past 5Y,ROI,52W High,Beta,Dividend %,Quick Ratio,Sales past 5Y,Gross Margin,52W Low,ATR,Employees,Current Ratio,Sales Q/Q,Oper. Margin,RSI (14),Volatility,Optionable,Debt/Eq,EPS Q/Q,Profit Margin,Rel Volume,Prev Close,Shortable,LT Debt/Eq,Earnings,Payout,Avg Volume,Price,Recom,SMA20,SMA50,SMA200,Volume,Change
-,-,-10.85,4.60%,2.36M,11.00%,8.09M,-,-,-62.38%,1.95M,-16.14%,-14.90M,-,-,2.30%,10.00%,-44.42%,0.00M,-,21.80%,-5.24%,3.10,-38.16%,1.46,2.35,-,-155.10%,65.00,-50.47%,-,-,-,-238.40%,2.91 - 11.20,-38.29%,-,-,54.50%,-,-69.37%,1.63,-,2.20,-,-,17.87%,0.36,15,2.20,-,-,39.83,11.38% 10.28%,No,0.00,68.70%,-,1.48,3.30,Yes,0.00,Feb 28 AMC,-,62.76K,3.43,1.00,-5.21%,-25.44%,-37.33%,"93,166",3.94%
-,-,-0.26,1.50%,268.98M,3.72%,2.25B,38.05,0.22,-0.64%,263.68M,-9.12%,-55.50M,-,0.05,-,9.96%,-12.26%,1.06B,2.12,-328.10%,25.95%,2.32,17.72%,12.61,0.66,650.00%,-0.90%,12.64,-38.73%,0.03,264.87,-,-1.90%,6.69 - 15.27,-0.48%,-,-,-28.70%,0.00%,-45.17%,2.20,-,0.70,16.40%,67.80%,25.11%,0.41,477,0.80,71.90%,5.30%,52.71,4.83% 5.00%,Yes,0.80,7.80%,-5.20%,0.96,7.78,Yes,0.80,Feb 27 AMC,-,11.31M,8.37,2.20,0.99%,-1.63%,-4.72%,"10,843,026",7.58%
```

If you only want your file to contain data from one run of the script, you do not need `a` to append, just use `w` instead.

Comment: Martin, thank you! My original intent was to have the header [Index, P/E, EPS (ttm),...] only appear at the top of today.csv, not every other line. How do I eliminate all the repeating versions?

Comment: I wasn't sure if your headers would all be the same. You could add a simple flag to ensure it is only written once, I have updated the script.